# Multiline \underbrace in math mode

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, underbrace

This refers to the following sophisticated [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/104398/underbrace-multiple-math-lines) by @David Carlisle for applying `\underbrace` to *multiline* expressions:

1. How can I still use `\underbrace` on a single-line expression? All I get from the common use of `\underbrace` with the proposed solution is

[image]

2. How can I get the brace under an expression that spans only *two* lines with the tip of the brace below the second line's part of the brace? All I get is

[image]

3. What is the most flexible approach to multiline '\underbrace' apart from obviously avoiding such notation when possible?

Here is (for convenience) David Carlisle's code with the problematic equations added:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\def\underbracex#1#2{\mathop{\vtop{\m@th\ialign{##\crcr
   $\hfil\displaystyle{#2}\hfil$\crcr
   \noalign{\kern3\p@\nointerlineskip}%
   #1\crcr\noalign{\kern3\p@}}}}\limits}

\def\underbracea{\underbracex\upbracefilla}

\def\upbracefilla{$\m@th \setbox\z@\hbox{$\braceld$}%
  \bracelu\leaders\vrule \@height\ht\z@ \@depth\z@\hfill 
\kern\p@\vrule \@width\p@\kern\p@\vrule \@width\p@\kern\p@\vrule \@width\p@
$}

\def\underbraceb{\underbracex\upbracefillb}

\def\upbracefillb{$\m@th \setbox\z@\hbox{$\braceld$}%
\vrule \@width\p@\kern\p@\vrule \@width\p@\kern\p@\vrule \@width\p@\kern\p@
 \leaders\vrule \@height\ht\z@ \@depth\z@\hfill\bracerd
  \braceld\leaders\vrule \@height\ht\z@ \@depth\z@\hfill
\kern\p@\vrule \@width\p@\kern\p@\vrule \@width\p@\kern\p@\vrule \@width\p@
$}


\def\underbracec{\underbracex\upbracefillc}

\def\upbracefillc{$\m@th \setbox\z@\hbox{$\braceld$}%
\vrule \@width\p@\kern\p@\vrule \@width\p@\kern\p@\vrule \@width\p@\kern\p@
\leaders\vrule \@height\ht\z@ \@depth\z@\hfill
\kern\p@\vrule \@width\p@\kern\p@\vrule \@width\p@\kern\p@\vrule \@width\p@
$}

\def\underbraced{\underbracex\upbracefill}
\def\upbracefill{$\m@th \setbox\z@\hbox{$\braceld$}%
\vrule \@width\p@\kern\p@\vrule \@width\p@\kern\p@\vrule \@width\p@\kern\p@
 \leaders\vrule \@height\ht\z@ \@depth\z@\hfill\braceru$}


\makeatother
\begin{document}

    \begin{align}
        \underbrace{a+b}_{=c} \\
        \underbracea{d + e} \\
        \underbraced{f+g}_{=h}
    \end{align}

\begin{align*}
 A ={}& B + \underbracea{C + D + E} \\
      &\underbraceb{{} + F + G}_{=:M} \\
      &\underbracec{{}+ H + I} \\
      &\underbraced{{} + J + K} + L
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[image]

There is an error in the old answer: the last clause was supposed to be variant `d` but it was written with no final letter so redefined the standard `\upbrace` macro to only make half a brace which was not the intention. Fixed below.

here I add one more variant `bd` that is a combination of `b` that had the "spike" and `d` which is the extending right half of a brace.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\def\underbracex#1#2{\mathop{\vtop{\m@th\ialign{##\crcr
   $\hfil\displaystyle{#2}\hfil$\crcr
   \noalign{\kern3\p@\nointerlineskip}%
   #1\crcr\noalign{\kern3\p@}}}}\limits}

\def\underbracea{\underbracex\upbracefilla}

\def\upbracefilla{$\m@th \setbox\z@\hbox{$\braceld$}%
  \bracelu\leaders\vrule \@height\ht\z@ \@depth\z@\hfill 
\kern\p@\vrule \@width\p@\kern\p@\vrule \@width\p@\kern\p@\vrule \@width\p@
$}

\def\underbraceb{\underbracex\upbracefillb}

\def\upbracefillb{$\m@th \setbox\z@\hbox{$\braceld$}%
\vrule \@width\p@\kern\p@\vrule \@width\p@\kern\p@\vrule \@width\p@\kern\p@
 \leaders\vrule \@height\ht\z@ \@depth\z@\hfill\bracerd
  \braceld\leaders\vrule \@height\ht\z@ \@depth\z@\hfill
\kern\p@\vrule \@width\p@\kern\p@\vrule \@width\p@\kern\p@\vrule \@width\p@
$}


\def\underbracec{\underbracex\upbracefillc}

\def\upbracefillc{$\m@th \setbox\z@\hbox{$\braceld$}%
\vrule \@width\p@\kern\p@\vrule \@width\p@\kern\p@\vrule \@width\p@\kern\p@
\leaders\vrule \@height\ht\z@ \@depth\z@\hfill
\kern\p@\vrule \@width\p@\kern\p@\vrule \@width\p@\kern\p@\vrule \@width\p@
$}

\def\underbraced{\underbracex\upbracefilld}
\def\upbracefilld{$\m@th \setbox\z@\hbox{$\braceld$}%
\vrule \@width\p@\kern\p@\vrule \@width\p@\kern\p@\vrule \@width\p@\kern\p@
 \leaders\vrule \@height\ht\z@ \@depth\z@\hfill\braceru$}

\def\underbracebd{\underbracex\upbracefillbd}
\def\upbracefillbd{$\m@th \setbox\z@\hbox{$\braceld$}%
\vrule \@width\p@\kern\p@\vrule \@width\p@\kern\p@\vrule \@width\p@\kern\p@
\bracerd\braceld
 \leaders\vrule \@height\ht\z@ \@depth\z@\hfill\braceru$}


\makeatother
\begin{document}

    \begin{align}
        \underbrace{a+b}_{=c} \\
        \underbracea{d + e} \\
        \underbracebd{f+g}_{=h}
    \end{align}

\begin{align*}
 A ={}& B + \underbracea{C + D + E} \\
      &\underbraceb{{} + F + G}_{=:M} \\
      &\underbracec{{}+ H + I} \\
      &\underbraced{{} + J + K} + L
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This solution is great, but there is an issue, if the package mathabx is loaded. Only \underbracec continues to work, the other versions have the dots vertically stretched. Is there any fix?

Comment: Mathx of mathabx redefines underbrace and its components, hence when loading mathx the issue shows up

Comment: Could you give an explanation on how this magic works? I'd like to add `underbraceab` as well as braket / parentheses and overbrace versions. But I am apparently a TeX-illiterate.